PyInstaller can't run a program with a foreign library
I have developed a Python program that interacts with the user through console inputs. I have converted this program into an executable file using PyInstaller. However, I have encountered an issue where I have installed external libraries in the script (matplotlib). When I run this script in the Windows console (cmd), I receive the following error message:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 2, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'matplotlib'
[27724] Failed to execute script 'poll_analysis' due to unhandled exception!

In my original script i installed everything propperly
How can I resolve this error?

You should append the following command
--paths=C:\...\<ProjectFolder>\.venv\Lib\site-packages

This should export most libraries.
The path should be the absolute path to your virtual environment.
So the complete command (for a console application) should look like this
pyinstaller --onefile --console --noconfirm --paths=C:\...\<ProjectFolder>\.venv\Lib\site-packages .\<file>.py


You need to install library along with it as
pyinstaller --onefile --hidden-import=matplotlib main.p

so for every library i want to add i can use this comand? when i want to add multiple librarys can i add more of them in this statement?

i am still getting the same error

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
